# phantomjs randomly stops; no error when accessing document

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I've recreated my bug with the following code for PhantomJS (Windows 10, 2.1.1)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://phantomjs.org/', function (status) {
    var doc = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document;
    });
    var extractor = function (title) {
        console.log("extractor:called with title = " + title)
        var a = doc.getElementById(title);
        var z = a.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[0];
        console.log("z: " + z);
    };
    extractor("feature-01");
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that I am creating a function that is evaluate in the page context to create a reference to 'document' that I can use with a JS function that is separately defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that was a right hunch about page context. You have to do all manipulations with the pages' DOM inside of page.evaluate() function, because native objects cannot be passed in and out of sandboxed page context, only primitive ones:

> The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!
>
> *From http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html*

So modified version of you script will be close to this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

// We want to receive console messages from the page context
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
};

page.open('http://phantomjs.org/', function (status) {

    var feature1 = page.evaluate(function () {

        var extractor = function (title) {
            console.log("extractor:called with title = " + title)
            return document.getElementById(title).childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].textContent.trim();
        };
        return extractor("feature-01");
    });

    console.log(feature1);
    phantom.exit();
});
```